# Space Complexity of Recursion

Tags: recursion

I have a question concerning the space complexity of recursive calls. Of course, for every recursive call there is a stack frame allocated in the call stack. But what about the variables? Let's say you define a variable in the recursive function, is this variable declared as often as the call happens, thus taking plenty of space?

Comment: Those variables will reside **in** those stack frames, will they not...? Anyway, there isn't necessarily a new frame for every call, because tail recursion _et al._ exist.

Comment: This is very language dependent. You should try to be more precise, with a language in mind and an example of code.